# Prevent a endless loop with rnd values

Tags: java, loops, infinite-loop

I once had in math a thing called computewall (in german: "Rechenwand", I don't know how this is called in english), you get there a pyramide and a few results. It looks e.g. like this:

```
    0
   0|0
  0|0|0
 4|0|0|0
5|9|0|0|0
```

Because I have holidays, I thought: "Well let's code a bit". So I tried writing a program that calculates me the one solution where numbers 1-15 only are appearing once in the pyramide.

The result of a number that is one row above between two numbers is calculated like you can see above in the bottom left corner. It is the absolute value of the substitution of the underneath numbers.

The project where I tried this is on Github and can be found here: https://github.com/SchoolGuy/Computewall

The problem is that the `do-while` loop at l.57 every time I run the program causes something like a endless loop (in fact is is just endless trying to fit the arguments). My question is how I can get rid of this problem!

P.S.: I commented out a lot to find the exact point, so don't be afraid of the size.

Edit 02.04.2016 15:50:

```
package Main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class computewall {

int[][] computewallInt = null;
int count;
ArrayList<Integer> sortedComputewall = null;
Random rnd = new Random();

public computewall() {
    count = 0;
    sortedComputewall = new ArrayList<>();
    computewallInt = new int[5][5];
    computewallInt[0][0] = 0;
    computewallInt[1][0] = 0;
    computewallInt[1][1] = 0;
    computewallInt[2][0] = 0;
    computewallInt[2][1] = 0;
    computewallInt[2][2] = 0;
    computewallInt[3][0] = 0;
    computewallInt[3][1] = 0;
    computewallInt[3][2] = 0;
    computewallInt[3][3] = 0;
    computewallInt[4][0] = 0;
    computewallInt[4][1] = 0;
    computewallInt[4][2] = 0;
    computewallInt[4][3] = 0;
    computewallInt[4][4] = 0;
    calculate();
    System.out.println("Rounds till solved: " + count);
    System.out.println("        " + computewallInt[0][0]);
    System.out.println("      " + computewallInt[1][0] + " | " + computewallInt[1][1]);
    System.out.println("    " + computewallInt[2][0] + " | " + computewallInt[2][1] + " | " + computewallInt[2][2]);
    System.out.println("  " + computewallInt[3][0] + " | " + computewallInt[3][1] + " | " + computewallInt[3][2] + " | " + computewallInt[3][3] + " | ");
    System.out.println(computewallInt[4][0] + " | " + computewallInt[4][1] + " | " + computewallInt[4][2] + " | " + computewallInt[4][3] + " | " + computewallInt[4][4]);
}

public void calculate() {
    boolean uniqueCheck = false;
    ArrayList<String> usedPosibilities = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("-------------------------");
    do {
        count++;
        sortedComputewall.clear();
        boolean duplicateCheck = false;
        boolean ohCheck = false;
        //Set values and search for duplicates and 0
        do {
            computewallValueReplace(computewallInt, 4, 0, rnd.nextInt(16));
            computewallValueReplace(computewallInt, 4, 1, rnd.nextInt(16));
            computewallValueReplace(computewallInt, 4, 2, rnd.nextInt(16));
            computewallValueReplace(computewallInt, 4, 3, rnd.nextInt(16));
            computewallValueReplace(computewallInt, 4, 4, rnd.nextInt(16));
            ///*
            if (computewallInt[4][0] == computewallInt[4][1] | computewallInt[4][0] == computewallInt[4][2] | computewallInt[4][0] == computewallInt[4][3] | computewallInt[4][0] == computewallInt[4][4]
                    | computewallInt[4][1] == computewallInt[4][2] | computewallInt[4][1] == computewallInt[4][3] | computewallInt[4][1] == computewallInt[4][4]
                    | computewallInt[4][2] == computewallInt[4][3] | computewallInt[4][2] == computewallInt[4][4] | computewallInt[4][3] == computewallInt[4][4]) {
                duplicateCheck = true;
            }
            if (computewallInt[4][0] == 0 | (computewallInt[4][1] == 0) | (computewallInt[4][1] == 0) | (computewallInt[4][3] == 0) | computewallInt[4][4] == 0) {
                ohCheck = true;
            }
        } while (duplicateCheck | ohCheck);
        usedPosibilities.add(String.valueOf(computewallInt [4][0]) + String.valueOf(computewallInt [4][1]) + String.valueOf(computewallInt [4][2])
                + String.valueOf(computewallInt [4][3]) + String.valueOf(computewallInt [4][4]));
        System.out.println("Lowest row calculated");

        //Rest of calculating
        computewallInt[3][0] = Math.abs(computewallInt[4][0] - computewallInt[4][1]);
        computewallInt[3][1] = Math.abs(computewallInt[4][1] - computewallInt[4][2]);
        computewallInt[3][2] = Math.abs(computewallInt[4][2] - computewallInt[4][3]);
        computewallInt[3][3] = Math.abs(computewallInt[4][3] - computewallInt[4][4]);
        computewallInt[2][0] = Math.abs(computewallInt[3][0] - computewallInt[3][1]);
        computewallInt[2][1] = Math.abs(computewallInt[3][1] - computewallInt[3][2]);
        computewallInt[2][2] = Math.abs(computewallInt[3][2] - computewallInt[3][3]);
        computewallInt[1][0] = Math.abs(computewallInt[2][0] - computewallInt[2][1]);
        computewallInt[1][1] = Math.abs(computewallInt[2][1] - computewallInt[2][2]);
        computewallInt[0][0] = Math.abs(computewallInt[1][0] - computewallInt[1][1]);
        System.out.println("Rest of table calculated");
        sortedComputewall.add(computewallInt[0][0]);
        sortedComputewall.add(computewallInt[1][0]);
        sortedComputewall.add(computewallInt[1][1]);
        sortedComputewall.add(computewallInt[2][0]);
        sortedComputewall.add(computewallInt[2][1]);
        sortedComputewall.add(computewallInt[2][2]);
        sortedComputewall.add(computewallInt[3][0]);
        sortedComputewall.add(computewallInt[3][1]);
        sortedComputewall.add(computewallInt[3][2]);
        sortedComputewall.add(computewallInt[3][3]);
        sortedComputewall.add(computewallInt[3][3]);
        sortedComputewall.add(computewallInt[4][4]);
        sortedComputewall.add(computewallInt[4][1]);
        sortedComputewall.add(computewallInt[4][2]);
        sortedComputewall.add(computewallInt[4][3]);
        Object[] sortedComputeWallInt = sortedComputewall.toArray();
        Arrays.sort(sortedComputeWallInt);
        if (sortedComputewall.contains(0) | !sortedComputewall.contains(1) | !sortedComputewall.contains(2) | !sortedComputewall.contains(3) | !sortedComputewall.contains(4) |
                !sortedComputewall.contains(5) | !sortedComputewall.contains(6) | !sortedComputewall.contains(7) | !sortedComputewall.contains(8) | !sortedComputewall.contains(9) |
                !sortedComputewall.contains(10) | !sortedComputewall.contains(11) | !sortedComputewall.contains(12) | !sortedComputewall.contains(13) | !sortedComputewall.contains(14) |
                !sortedComputewall.contains(15)) {
            uniqueCheck = true;
        }
        System.out.println("-------------------------");
    } while (uniqueCheck);
}

public void computewallValueReplace(int[][] array, int row, int position, int value) {
    array[row][position] = value;
}
}
```

This is the complete class.

Comment: Could you please include the code in your question?

Comment: It can be viewed at github

Comment: post only the relevant portion of the code in your question. No one would like to go to github and see the code.

Comment: You need to figure out why this condition never goes false: while (duplicateCheck | ohCheck); Use your debugger and step through it. I'm not afraid of the size but it would be easier for someone who has never looked at your code to wade through it if you stripped it down to a minimal example.

Comment: That is the point this is no infinite loop

Comment: Where is the diffrence? The first one checks both and the second one checks both, but breaks when the first one is true.

Comment: Don't use bitwise or ("|"), use logical or ("||") instead.

Comment: Why? What is the diffrence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some big problems with this code, but I'll answer your specific question about the while loop. Here is your code:

```
    do {
        computewallValueReplace(computewallInt, 4, 0, rnd.nextInt(16));
        computewallValueReplace(computewallInt, 4, 1, rnd.nextInt(16));
        computewallValueReplace(computewallInt, 4, 2, rnd.nextInt(16));
        computewallValueReplace(computewallInt, 4, 3, rnd.nextInt(16));
        computewallValueReplace(computewallInt, 4, 4, rnd.nextInt(16));
        ///*
        if (computewallInt[4][0] == computewallInt[4][1] | computewallInt[4][0] == computewallInt[4][2] | computewallInt[4][0] == computewallInt[4][3] | computewallInt[4][0] == computewallInt[4][4]
                | computewallInt[4][1] == computewallInt[4][2] | computewallInt[4][1] == computewallInt[4][3] | computewallInt[4][1] == computewallInt[4][4]
                | computewallInt[4][2] == computewallInt[4][3] | computewallInt[4][2] == computewallInt[4][4] | computewallInt[4][3] == computewallInt[4][4]) {
            duplicateCheck = true;
        }
        if (computewallInt[4][0] == 0 | (computewallInt[4][1] == 0) | (computewallInt[4][1] == 0) | (computewallInt[4][3] == 0) | computewallInt[4][4] == 0) {
            ohCheck = true;
        }
    } while (duplicateCheck | ohCheck);
```

Observe that if either `duplicateCheck` or `ohCheck` is set to `true` on the first pass of this do-while, then you're stuck in an infinite loop. They come into the loop as `false`, but can be set to `true` in the first pass of the loop. There is no condition in the loop that would ever set either of them to false, and thus the condition `(duplicateCheck | ohCheck)` would always be satisfied.

Comment: And the rest of problems? I have the program running in the background, will it ever give the result?

Comment: You do something really similar with `uniqueCheck`. So I doubt it will finish. It shouldn't take more than a second or two to execute...if it's taking longer, you're likely in an infinite loop.

Comment: Thx, I will search. Could you please also search I'm a real newbie :(

Comment: Works, but it will take a while because I can't prevent that the rnd function returns double possibilities. Currently I am at 1 billion steps

Answer (score 0):

When one of the checks(duplicateCheck | ohCheck) was ever true then the var was never set to false, so there I had my endless loop